# Poincare Inequality Involving Plancherel

Tags: poincare-duality

I need help in proving this question:

Suppose the function $f$ is differentiable and $\frac{1}{2}$-periodic (i.e., more than just 1-periodic). Show that the Poincare inequality holds with a better constant:
$$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx-\left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right)^2\leq \pi^2\int (f'(x))^2dx.$$

Comment: Have you seen the proof of the usual Poincare inequality? See if you can modify it to suit this case.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the usual Poincare inequality but I am unable to modify it accordingly.

Comment: Please post the original proof of the Poincare inequality and its statement. I will see with you if we can make modifications.